# Can I travel for leisure to Australia with a 600 Business Stream visa?

Tags: australia

I have a valid 600 Business Stream Visa (valid for one year with multiple entries) to travel to Australia. I travelled to Perth earlier in the year for business meetings.

With this visa am I allowed to enter Australia for leisure? I don't intend to participate in any business activities on this trip.

Thanks for your help.